# How to import certificate (.crt) file into AWS CloudHSM Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudhsm

I have read documentation in AWS CloudHSM.

I tried to import certificate using command below

```
pkcs11-tool --module /opt/cloudhsm/lib/libcloudhsm_pkcs11.so -l --pin <my_pin> --write-object my_self_signed_cert.der --type cert --id 123
```

I got output

```
SDK Version: 2.03
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x1)

C_CreateObject failed with error CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE : 0x000000d0
error: PKCS11 function C_CreateObject failed: rv = CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE (0xd0)

Aborting.
```

Has anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudHSM does not support importing certificate as of now. It only allows importing keys. For importing keys in AWS CloudHSM you should use the tool provided by AWS CloudHSM only. The link for the same is 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/manage-keys.html. Follow all the steps mentioned in the official documentation before importing keys. You have to do all the setup and configuration to get access to your AWS CloudHSM.